# Vertex issue occuring while executing query

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, apache-tez

Receiving vertex issue while executing a query.

Error:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. 
Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 3, vertexId=vertex_1683264843276_149409_1_01, diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_1683264843276_149409_1_01 
[Map 3] killed/failed due to: ROOT_INPUT_INIT_FAILURE, 
Vertex Input: i_bsm_starmrt_ils_monthend_info_tb initializer failed,
vertex=vertex_1683264843276_149409_1_01 [Map 3],
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist:
```

Tried to execute query

Answer (score 0):

The error is indicating missing file path.

`org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist:`

Check if table i_bsm_starmrt_ils_monthend_info_tb has any missing files.